# Не отображается форма django

Tags: django

У меня не отображается поле `text` на странице. Передаю в контекст. Вывожу через `{{ form.text }}`. Ссылка [гитхаб](https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/dear_diary_project), [ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkpEtE_x6xk)

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Entry

class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('text', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'textarea', 'placeholder' : 'О чем ты думаешь?'})
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Entry
from .forms import EntryForm
from django.views import *
from django.views import View

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = EntryForm()

    context = {'form' : form}

    return render(request, 'entries/add.html', context)
```

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Дневник</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="hero is-info">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title">
                    Дневник
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section">

      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add' %}">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="field">
                   <div class="control">
                       {{ form.text }}
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
                   <div class="control">
                       <button class="button is-link">Submit</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
       </form>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('calendar/', views.calendar, name='blog-calendar'),
    path('rukovoditelya/', views.rukovoditelya, name='blog-rukovoditelya'),
    path('biography/', views.biography, name='blog-biography'),
    path('diary/', views.diary, name='blog-diary'),
    path('struktura/', views.struktura, name='blog-struktura'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='blog-contact'),
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
]
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/fc/lib/main.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'blog/fc/lib/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/moment.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/fc/lib/locales-all.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/index.js' %}"></script>

    {% if title %}
        <title>Блог - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Блог</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Блог руководителя управления транспорта и автодорог области</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <!--<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Главная</a>-->

          <!--<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">Контакты</a>-->
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Создать пост</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Профиль</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выйти</a>
              {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Авторизоваться</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Регистрация</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Меню</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>
              <ul class="list-group">
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Последние новости</a></li>
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}" li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Дневник</li>
                <a href="{% url 'blog-calendar' %}" li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Календарь</li>
                <a href="{% url 'blog-about' %}" li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Контакты</li>
                <a href="{% url 'blog-contact' %}" li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Обратная связь</a></li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="content-section">
            <h4>Об управлении</h4>
            <p class='text-muted'>
              <img src="/media/authorblog.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
              <p><strong></strong><br>
            </p>

              <p>Уважаемые посетители сайта! Мы рады приветствовать вас, и надеемся, что информация, представленная на сайте, будет для Вас полезной.
              <a href="{% url 'blog-rukovoditelya' %}">Подробнее →</a>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small blue-grey lighten-5">

      <div style="background-color: #4285f4">
        <div class="container">

          <!-- Grid row-->
          <div class="row py-4 d-flex align-items-center">

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 text-center text-md-left mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h6 class="mb-0">Присоединяйтесь к нам в социальных сетях!</h6>
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 text-center text-md-right">

              <!-- Facebook -->
              <a class="fb-ic">
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f white-text mr-4"> </i>
              </a>
              <!-- vk -->
              <a class="">
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-vk white-text mr-4"> </i>
              </a>

              <!-- <a class="gplus-ic">
                <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g white-text mr-4"> </i>
              </a>

              <a class="li-ic">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in white-text mr-4"> </i>
              </a> -->
              <!--Instagram-->
              <a class="ins-ic">
                <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram white-text"> </i>
              </a>

            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

          </div>
          <!-- Grid row-->

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer Links -->
      <div class="container text-center text-md-left mt-5">

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row mt-3 dark-grey-text">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">

            <!-- Content -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Наша компания</h6>
            <hr class="deep-purple accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p></p>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Полезные ссылки</h6>
            <hr class="deep-purple accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p>
              <a class="dark-grey-text" href="{% url 'blog-contact' %}">Задать вопрос</a>
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="dark-grey-text" href="#">Вакансия</a>
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="dark-grey-text" href="{% url 'blog-contact' %}">Обратная связь</a>
            </p>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto mb-4">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Аккаунт</h6>
            <hr class="deep-purple accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p>
              <a class="dark-grey-text" href="{% url 'login' %}">Войти</a>
            </p>
            <p>
              <a class="dark-grey-text" href="{% url 'register' %}">Регистрация</a>
            </p>


          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Контакты</h6>
            <hr class="deep-purple accent-3 mb-4 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto" style="width: 60px;">
            <p>
              <i class="fas fa-home mr-3"></i> </p>
            <p>
              <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-3"></i> </p>
            <p>
              <i class="fas fa-phone mr-3"></i> </p>
            <p>
              <i class="fas fa-print mr-3"></i> </p>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

      </div>
      <!-- Footer Links -->

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-black-50 py-3">© 2021 Copyright:
        <a class="dark-grey-text" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e758dd1d08.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: проверьте что выводит `{{ form }}`

Comment: Здраствуйте, куда прописать код?

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте туда код

Answer (score 0):

Это должно работать, но лучше отдельно определить методы POST и GET. Используйте  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/

```
def add(request):

    form = EntryForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        return render(request, 'entries/add.html', context)
    return render(request, 'entries/add.html', context)
```

Comment: Не работают, может из за этого что два приложения

Comment: покажите urls.py приложения, возможно вы не верно указали name для redirect(), так как у меня все работает.

Comment: добавил urls.py

Comment: 1. выложите urls.py где указаны приложения + структуру шаблонов HTML + функцию index()

Comment: добавил код urls.py

Comment: скинь ссылку на git твоего проекта

Comment: можно с вами связаться через дискорд и показать. Мой дискорд RAVEN#7984